# VueJS DOM and API Loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way I can ask the *VueJS* to wait for a while before handling the **DOM** bugs?

I have for example a `select` that receives a`v-model` coming from the API, but as VueJS loads the DOM first before the `http` call, it already accuses`select` error

> type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got Undefined.

This error is right because it draws the **DOM** with nothing in the select, but then it fills in with my call to **API**. Is there any way I can ask VueJS to wait a little bit for me to bring the **API** data and then it checks **DOM**?

Thank you!!

*Note: I know that initializing the parameter with empty array works, but wanted another way without being manual*

Comment: You can always use `v-if` to check if your v-model has data and in case it doesn't just don't display select or display a placeholder for it. Though, that is a job you have to do manually.

Comment: Hmmm that's a way!! but i prefer errors in console instead do it manually =(

Comment: Browser is generating / handling DOM errors, not the Vue. Vue only changes the DOM as needed. And as there is no possibility to ask the browser to postpone the DOM parsing, you should always a create valid DOM.

Comment: This is a common async architecture problem/question. Being lazy (not wanting to do a lot of manual v-if or v-show etc.) and thinking of UX at the same time - I just wrapped my whole SPA container with a single v-show that is waiting for data (ajax backend), showing a "please wait spinner"  and when data is available hiding it and showing the SPA. Another option is, maybe, to use "wise placeholders" (like FB and some UX guys prefer) that are just showing empty containers while loading data...). Depends, as allways :D

Comment: Thanks man, another good way to solve this! :)